# PHP Sessions limit

Tags: php, session

I'm in the process of upgrading a website that I built a while ago .. This update is due to a bug in passing data between pages front and back.

I'm storing all data that should be passed in `$_SESSION` .. But I remember reading somewhere that this is not good, especially when the data is big .. So I was wondering, what is the limit to use when dealing with the `$_SESSION` and if there are any alternatives for storing and retrieving data for runtime ..

I also have a save feature that stores the data in the database for later use.

Hope I can find the answer to this with the experts over here :)

Comment: The basic rule of thumb is that you should store frequently-used, fairly static data in your `$_SESSION`. If the data isn't used frequently, or is apt to change throughout a user's session, keep it in the database and extract it as necessary.

Comment: If you use plain sessions (default, filebased storage), the problem won't occur very fast. All data in a $_SESSION is serialized and written to a file. This is very fast.
Are you sure the size of the session is causing you troubles? How big are the files? (Simply look in your session-storage directory to get an impression).
Are you experiencing any problems? If not, I would advice not to change it.

Comment: Ok Matt, but how can I reach this approach?!! it is actually good, but say I have a temp table that I will use .. How can I reach your approach, and how to clear this table when the user leaves?

Comment: @ErwinMoller .. No, currently there are no problems with the speed .. The problem I'm facing is with the data storing .. Sometimes data is lost!! So I was looking to change it to a temp table .. But I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: I'm thinking of creating a temp table that is there all the time .. and to add the data to it along with a time stamp .. and every 24 hrs I clear the table via a cron job. Is this a good approach ??

Comment: "sometimes data is lost" - you should find out *when* that happens and then you can work on *why* it happens. After that you can optimize your session storage mechanism, if it really is the culprit.

Comment: @sikas Unless you have some really unstable server, I doubt the lost data is due to PHPs sessionhandling. It is very reliable in my experience. This can be hard, but try to figure out a scenario where you can reproduce the lost-data-problem, and then investigate.